# Calculating the number of address lines needed for a memory in 3-dimensional memory array

Tags: memory, rom

Using address multiplexing where the address lines are used by the row and
column selector of a 3-dimensional memory array with the third dimension
being 8 bits, how many address lines are needed for a memory with a bit
capacity of 524288 bits?

My approach:

524288/8 = 65536

log_2(65536) = 16

Is is 16? Or I'm supposed to divide it by 2 since we are using address multiplexing? I'm confused.

Comment: What does the instructor say?

Comment: What did the instructor tell you the multiple dimensions were?

Comment: Does 65536 locations mean that there are 256 rows and 256 columns?

Comment: That was the only given information about the problem.

Comment: You should ask the instructor for clarification, or go back and review the materials for the course.

Comment: It depends on the number of rows and columns. Are they equal?

Comment: I see, how would it be if the row and columns are equal?

Comment: If they are equal, update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just guide you to the answer. You have already found out the number of address locations: \$ A =  65536\$, where each location addresses a byte. Rows and columns are the two dimensions to address the memory.

1. Calculate the number of rows and columns in the memory structure, where \$R . C = A\$.
2. Calculate how many bits are needed to represent a row-address and  a column-address. Since the addresses are multiplexed, choose the address bus width as the larger of the two.

You say, number of rows and columns are equal. So that makes things easier.

Comment: In the case that R = C, the answer would be 256, correct?

Comment: Yea.... So the address-width/lines would be ..?

Comment: It would still be 256 since they're equal. Right...?

Comment: Why do you need 256 address lines to address 256 locations?

Comment: Because R.C = A, so There would be 256 columns and 256 rows, with 8 bits every cell?

Comment: I think you need to revisit your basics (what is address, row-address, column-address, data, address line, data line, etc). You need only log2(256) = 8-bit address ie., 8 address lines,  to address 256 locations. Location here refers to any row or column in the memory.